# Bottle necks to body building?

Tags: bodybuilding, protein, testosterone

I often hear youtubers talking about pushing the nutrients and drugs into the muscle via the increased bloodflow during exercise. It makes me wonder, let's say if someone hypothetically took weight gainer, with anabolics, and did nothing else, no exercise. Would they be bottle necked and unable to grow muscles?

It's common knowledge that essential amino acids cannot be stored for later use, so they need to be administered to the muscles at the intended time for the muscles to grow. If the muscles are bottle necked from growing by the lack of bloodflow, wouldn't this mean the person would have to ingest protein and anabolics before the workout?

This idea is very intimidating because as far as I knew earlier, insulin from ingesting food will be present in the blood. If the person starts burning more energy than is coming from the stomach, the body will start making glucose out of proteins instead of fats. So eating before a workout is a good way to loose muscle mass.

So I am really confused about this bloodflow and pushing nutrients and drugs to muscles idea.

Comment: Can you share a link to one of the YouTubers speaking about nutrients and blood flow?

Answer (score 3):

> It makes me wonder, let's say if someone hypothetically took weight gainer, with anabolics, and did nothing else, no exercise. Would they be bottle necked and unable to grow muscles?

No. People who take steroids without exercising do gain muscle.

https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199607043350101

> If the muscles are bottle necked from growing by the lack of bloodflow, wouldn't this mean the person would have to ingest protein and anabolics before the workout?

No, muscles do not become "bottle-necked" when not engaged in exercise. There's still blood flowing to the muscles at rest.

> This idea is very intimidating because as far as I knew earlier, insulin from ingesting food will be present in the blood. If the person starts burning more energy than is coming from the stomach, the body will start making glucose out of proteins instead of fats. So eating before a workout is a good way to loose muscle mass.

That seems incredibly unlikely.

> So I am really confused about this bloodflow and pushing nutrients and drugs to muscles idea.

You should perhaps reevaluate whether these YouTubers are actually people that are worth listening to.

Comment: >No. People who take steroids without exercising do gain muscle. 
True, but productivity and effectiveness is important. like if you are washing one dish per hour you are still technically "washing dishes".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KPnkFL6XAM